# We have $101$ tenorist, every two cooperated in exactly one concert, but there is no concert in which all participated.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

> *We have $101$ tenorist, every two cooperated in exactly one concert, but there is no concert in which all participated.
> Prove that someone  participated in at least $11$ concerts.*

This is an old problem from Moscow math Olympiad. I did try to solve it but somehow I can't. Any thoughts?

Say we have $T_1,T_2,...,T_{101}$ tenorists and $A_1,A_2,...A_n$ concerts. So every pair $\{T_i,T_j\}$ is ''connected'' to exactly one concert. So we have:

$$ \sum {\deg(A_i)\choose 2} = \sum \deg(\{T_i,T_j\}) = {101\choose 2}\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

We have to prove that the degree of some $T_j$ is at least $11$. Suppose there is no such $j$, then for every $T_j$ the degree is at most $10$ and we have:
$$ \sum \deg(A_i) = \sum \deg(T_i) \leq 1010 \;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Is the assumption that there has been no attack involving more than 2 of these 101 terrorists?

Comment: The model I have in my mind is the following. If there where $p^2$ terrorists, $p$ a prime, then it is possible that they all participated in exactly $p$ attacks. This is because the modulo $p$ plane $\Bbb{F}_p\times\Bbb{F}_p$ can be partitioned into $p$ parallel lines of respective slopes $\infty,0,1,2,\ldots,p-1$. Each terrorist is a point on that plane. Each attack was done by one of those lines. Two points determine a unique line, so every pair of terrorists participated in a single attack. But, how to prove that this is "optimal", and how to lift the assumption that $p=10$ is also ok.

Comment: To get an idea of what goes on I would first try to prove that with 5 terrorists somebody took part in at least three attacks. Then hope for a light-bulb experience :-/

Comment: De Bruijn-Erdos theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an arbitrary tenorist, say $T_1$. He is involved in at most $10$ concerts, which combined pairs him once with each of the remaining $100$ tenorists. Hence, at least one of these concerts, say $A_k$, must involve at least $11$ tenorists.

Given concert $A_k$ involving $m\ge11$ tenorists, and a tenorist $T_p$ not in $A_k$, for each tenorist $T_i$ in $A_k$ there will be a unique concert which includes $T_i$ and $T_p$. This gives a list of $m$ concert, one for each $T_i\in A_k$, and these must all be distinct concert different from $A_k$ since no two members of $A_k$ may be in another concert.

So, this gives $m\ge11$ concert in which $T_p$ is a member.

*Would the result also be true with a smaller number of tenorists? Unless I'm missing something, my proof should also work if there are $92$ tenorists.*

Comment: I believe it does. It would be interesting to extend to arbitrary number of terrorists, $n$, and what lower bound can be put on the one who participated in the most attacks...

Comment: We see that the condition not all participated in a single attack is crucial for existence of $T_p$.